# How to select a docked VCL Form in C++Builder

Tags: c++builder, vcl

I have a VCL Forms Application in C++Builder. I have a main form with four docking `TPageControl`. The program is a graphics draw program that can open images into their own VCL form which can be docked on a `TPageControl` for side-by-side viewing. When a VCL form is docked, selecting it with the mouse makes the underlaying main form the `ActiveForm`.

How can I select a docked VCL form and make it the `ActiveForm`? I need to know which docked VCL form is selected so I can manipulate the correct image.

For testing, I am using the loop below to display all the VCL Form names in a `TListBox` and show the `ActiveForm` name in a `TEdit`. This code is in a button event on the main form. I can select a free-floating VCL Form and make it the `ActiveForm`, but not a docked VCL form.

```cpp
void __fastcall TMainForm1::Button3Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  ListBox1->Items->Clear();
  Edit1->Text="";
  UnicodeString n="";

  int C = Screen->FormCount;
  for( int i = 0; i < C; ++i )
  {
    TForm* form = Screen->Forms[i];
    n = form->Name;
    ListBox1->Items->Add(form->Name); //List all Form Names

    if( Screen->ActiveForm == form ){
      Edit1->Text = form->Name;  //Active Form Name
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does the ActiveControl return for the underlying main form or the screen?

Comment: When the 2nd Form is floating clicking on the form shows itself as the ActiveControl. When the form is docked clicking it shows the button on the mainform that opened the form. So I can not identify the select form when it is docked. The results are the same for Screen and MainForm.

//Form is Floating
Screen->ActiveControl->Handle: 47516806
Screen->ActiveControl->Name: AboutForm_1

//Form is Docked
Screen->ActiveControl->Handle: 48892580
Screen->ActiveControl->Name: Button6